# In Unity/UNet: How do you properly spawn a `NetworkPlayer`?

Tags: unity, unity-networking

In Unity/UNet: 
How do you properly spawn a `NetworkPlayer`? Right now, I'm doing it like this from inside a `NetworkManager` derived class:

```
   public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId) {
        NetworkPlayer newPlayer = Instantiate<NetworkPlayer>(m_NetworkPlayerPrefab);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(newPlayer);
        NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, newPlayer.gameObject, playerControllerId);
   }
```

This code snippet works pretty well and both **clients** can communicate with each other. However, there are a few little issues that arise only on the **host**:

1. In **Unity's hierarchy-view** on the **host**, there are only two `NetworkPlayer` instances. Shouldn't there be four **NetworkPlayer** instances on the **host**? Two **client** instances and two **server** instances? If so, do you have any ideas what could cause the missing `NetworkPlayer` instances?
2. The two **NetworkPlayer** instances have both, their `isClient` and `isServer` flags set to `true`. But only one of the has it's `isLocalPlayer` flag set. Now I wonder if this behavior is as intended? And if so, how do you distinguish between the **client** and the **server** instance of a `NetworkPlayer`?
3. Two player behavior: If the **remote client** sends a `[Command]` that changes a `[SyncVar]` on the **server**, then on the **host**, the `[SyncVar]-hook` is called only on the `NetworkPlayer` instance that represents the **remote** `NetworkPlayer`. The `[SyncVar]-hook` is not called on the **host's** `"isLocalPlayer-NetworkPlayer"` instance. Shouldn't the `[SyncVar]-hook` be called on both `NetworkPlayer` instances?

Any advise is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> In Unity's hierarchy-view on the host, there are only two
>   NetworkPlayer instances. Shouldn't there be four NetworkPlayer
>   instances on the host? Two client instances and two server instances?
>   If so, do you have any ideas what could cause the missing
>   NetworkPlayer instances?

No, two is the correct number. The only difference between the `Host` and the `Client` when it comes to things, is that the `Clients` defer to the `Host` about the position of the `GameObjects` and their state. If the `Host` moves an object 1 unit to the left, the `Clients` will all move their version to match.

> The two NetworkPlayer instances have both, their isClient and isServer
>   flags set to true. But only one of the has it's isLocalPlayer flag
>   set. Now I wonder if this behavior is as intended? And if so, how do
>   you distinguish between the client and the server instance of a
>   NetworkPlayer?

`NetworkPlayer` doesn't have those attributes, `Network` has them. `Network.isClient` will be `true` if the `Network` instance is a `Client`, likewise `Network.isServer` will be `true` if the `Network` instance is the `Host`.

`isLocalPlayer` will be `true` if the `NetworkPlayer` instance is the instance representing the local machine in the game. Only one `NetworkPlayer` instance will have an `isLocalPlayer` value of `true` in a running instance of your game. Think of this variable as the "me" flag: think "this object is me".

> Two player behavior: If the remote client sends a [Command] that
>   changes a [SyncVar] on the server, then on the host, the
>   [SyncVar]-hook is called only on the NetworkPlayer instance that
>   represents the remote NetworkPlayer. The [SyncVar]-hook is not called
>   on the host's "isLocalPlayer-NetworkPlayer" instance. Shouldn't the
>   [SyncVar]-hook be called on both NetworkPlayer instances?

No. As before, the `isLocalPlayer=true` `NetworkPlayer` instance is the avatar/character controlled by the human on the `Host` machine. The `[Command]` is being called by the `Client` to ask the `Host` to update the state of the `Host's` copy of the `Client's` `NetworkPlayer` instance. The `Host` will update the value on it's copy of the `GameObject` representing the remote human player, then forward the change to the other `Clients` in the game.

--

One thing to consider here is the directionality of the various pieces of the networking code:

`[Command]`s are sent from `Client` to `Host`

`[ClientRPC]`s are sent from `Host` to `Clients`

`[SyncVar]`s are sent from `Host` to `Clients`

See the documentation [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html) for more information.